# can not start jboss server in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss7.x

I am developing a JSF project. I want to use JBoss as the server.
I had defined jboss server in eclipse, but I cannot start to JBoss server because errors occurred.

error:

```
        10:01:45,390 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
        10:01:51,312 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
        10:01:51,703 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
        10:02:03,109 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
            at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
            at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:266) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
            at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_21]
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MİLLİSECONDS
            at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_21]
            at org.jboss.as.threads.ThreadsParser.parseTimeSpec(ThreadsParser.java:874)
            at org.jboss.as.threads.ThreadsParser.parseUnboundedQueueThreadPool(ThreadsParser.java:518)
            at org.jboss.as.ejb3.subsystem.EJB3Subsystem12Parser.parseThreadPools(EJB3Subsystem12Parser.java:1103)
            at org.jboss.as.ejb3.subsystem.EJB3Subsystem12Parser.readElement(EJB3Subsystem12Parser.java:297)
            at org.jboss.as.ejb3.subsystem.EJB3Subsystem12Parser.readElement(EJB3Subsystem12Parser.java:55)
            at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:894) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
            at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:330) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
            at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
            at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
            at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
            ... 3 more

        10:02:03,171 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
        10:02:03,218 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" stopped in 0ms
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I have downloaded the latest Jboss As adapters. On the other hand I solved the problem.

Error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MİLLİSECONDS

I work on operation system which is Turkish. So Jboss changes characters of this Enum according to system configuration language.

```
   MILLISECONDS -> MİLLİSECONDS
```

I solved the problem as following way:

Open Eclipse. Click server bar. Double click Jboss 7.x. Click "Open Launch configuration.
Add to "-Duser.language=en" end of line of VM arguments

If you want to image, go to  http://blog.sahinyazilim.net/?p=123

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the latest Jboss AS adapters from Eclipse Marketplace? Also are there any applications, connection pools etc already deployed on the server?

Answer (score -1):

"I work on operation system which is Turkish. So Jboss changes characters of this Enum according to system configuration language.    MILLISECONDS -> MİLLİSECONDS"

Yeah definitaly after i set computer language in English problem fixed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).